# google+ comments and javascript

Tags: javascript, comments, google-plus, document, responsive

I'm working on a wordpress plugin that is supposed to add a google+ comments section next to an embedded video. I can use javascript to get the correct width initially, but the scripts that auto load in the Iframe document automatically change the size to 100% width if the browser size is changed (see images). I am having serious difficulty accessing the div in the document under the Iframe to change its with to what I want when it resizes.

[how it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOdFz.png)

[after adjusting the browser size it jumps below and goes to 100% width.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo3LL.png)

I'm using thise code to generate the comments section:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<div id="comments"></div>
<script>
gapi.comments.render('comments', {
    href: [URL],
    width: 'comments_w',
    first_party_property: 'BLOGGER',
    view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD'
});
```

"comments_w" is a variable that is calculated in an earlier javascript based on the space left after the video's width is calculated.

this is the Iframe being gnerated inside the comments div

```
<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 1138px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 616px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1480032087207" name="I0_1480032087207" src="https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cellcycle.net%2Ftemppage%2F&amp;width=341&amp;first_party_property=BLOGGER&amp;view_type=FILTERED_POSTMOD&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cellcycle.net&amp;search=&amp;hash=&amp;gsrc=3p&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.CUXyo_wPfp0.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMYqx5cA6SdMRKSM5YaRVPo-xpcPg#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Cscroll%2Copenwindow&amp;id=I0_1480032087207&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cellcycle.net&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=30831408" data-gapiattached="true" title="Comment on this"></iframe>
    #document == $0
        <html est...>
</iframe>
```

There is a div inside the body that controls the width. I just need to find a way to access it with javascript and change the size whenever the browser is resized. I already have the function I want being called whenever it is resized. I am just having a hard time with getting jQuery to find the element inside the document.

Comment: if the iframe is in a different origin, you wont be able to do anything with its contents

Answer (score 0):

Ok confirmed this is not possible. as Jaromanda X pointed out the origin must be the same. I looked into origin policy here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and found out for sure. Kind of unfortunate for me, but hope this prevents anyone else from wasting time trying to.